# How to improve INSERT speed in large table that has unique constraint

Tags: mysql, performance, index, insert

I have a simple MyISAM table:

```
explain entities;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(50) | YES  | UNI | NULL              |                |
| created_at | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

that is expected to have 10s of millions of rows (or even more) eventually. I noticed that as the number of rows in the table increases, insert statements start to take longer. This is expected, as the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html) states that "the size of the table slows down the insertion of indexes by log N, assuming B-tree indexes". I read in [another question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35051/mysql-improve-performance-for-one-row-insert-into-table-with-unique-constraint) that `LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE` can be used to improve insert speed, but I found this to have a negligible effect. Are there any other pointers on how to improve insertion speed, other than the ones listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html)? For example, would partitioning the table help with insertion speed? What guidelines can I use for determining if my insertion speeds are already at a near optimum?

System info:
MySQL 5.1.67-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 
Running on Linode VM with 512 MB RAM and quad-core processor

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem could be your RAM, for [`LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-index.html) to make a difference you should have the **index size** < [`key_buffer_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) < **Available RAM**

To see your current index size use [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//show-table-status.html).

Also [`LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-index.html) works only for MyISAM, for InnoDB you could try the blackhole method:

```
create table t like innodbtable;
alter table t engine = blackhole;
insert into t select * from innodbtable WHERE indexedRow<>''; -- Get creative in order to stimulate reading of data and indexes you need
```

[source](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/70-Innodb-cache-preloading-using-blackhole.html) , for more information on InnoDB pre-loading see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//innodb-buffer-pool.html) and [this](http://books.google.ro/books?id=BL0NNoFPuAQC&pg=PA277&lpg=PA277&dq=innodb%20LOAD%20INDEX%20INTO%20CACHE&source=bl&ots=COVLzttG4P&sig=FLYllXOQDT2D7p72ac-kxCiyMWY&hl=ro&sa=X&ei=FEs4UcvhCMjL0AWkn4HYCA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=innodb%20LOAD%20INDEX%20INTO%20CACHE&f=false).

To estimate index usage see [this](http://www.techiegyan.com/2009/11/19/calculate-table-size-index-size-mysql/) or [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,377625,378101#msg-378101) .

For example I have a table with 32 Mil records in it and the data size is 2.33 GB (2,496,806,620) and the index size is 2.08 GB (2,230,159,360). So your table should be at least 5 times smaller to be able to fit the RAM limit. Also don't forget I said **Available RAM** = the ram left after excluding system, mysql (other than the `key_buffer_size`) & other software, so that would leave you at best with 350MB.

Here is my table for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `b_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `varchar1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `varchar2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `varchar3` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastModified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `links_id_email` (`a_id`,`varchar1`),
  KEY `domain_index` (`varchar2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```